# How to display two columns with multiple rows php

Tags: php, mysql

I adopted code given in this example:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

It is Table from Phpmyadmin.

Table: post

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|  id  |   a   |   b   |   c   |   d   |   e   |  .... 
-------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |  AA1  |   BB2 |   CC3 |  DD4  |   EE5 |  .... 
-------------------------------------------------------
```

The code is as follows (PHP):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE id ORDER BY id ASC"; 
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  { 
    echo $row["a"];  // Out: AA1
    echo $row["b"];  // Out: BB2
    echo $row["c"];  // Out: CC3
    echo $row["d"];  // Out: DD4
    echo $row["e"];  // Out: EE5
    .
    .
    .
}
```

When I add a column to the database (phpmyadmin) or I import information (sql), It gives an error message and its message is as follows:

```
Error:
SQL query: 
MySQL said: Documentation
#1118 - Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. 
In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.
```

I changed the table with the code above and it is as follows: ($data)

```
----------------------------
|  id  |  name   |  value  |
----------------------------
|  1   |    a    |   AA1   |
----------------------------
|  2   |    b    |   BB2   |
----------------------------
|  3   |    c    |   CC3   |
----------------------------
|  4   |    d    |   DD4   |
----------------------------
|  5   |    e    |   EE5   |
----------------------------
.
.
.
```

Now the modified code is as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `post` (`name`,`value`) WHERE id ORDER BY id ASC"; 
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$data = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  { 
    echo $data[$row['value']]['a'];  // out : AA1
    echo $data[$row['value']]['b'];  // out : BB2
    echo $data[$row['value']]['c'];  // out : CC3
    echo $data[$row['value']]['d'];  // out : DD4
    echo $data[$row['value']]['e'];  // out : EE5
    .
    .
    .
}
```

When I refresh the page And It gives an error message and its message is as follows:

```
Notice: Undefined index: AA1
Notice: Undefined index: BB2
Notice: Undefined index: CC3
Notice: Undefined index: DD4
Notice: Undefined index: EE5
```

What could be the reason and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your SELECT statement is invalid in your modified version.

Comment: and `$data` is never populated.

Comment: You have too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Comment: That's the way it changed

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files. **Stay away from w3schools**, the advice there is really bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY id ASC"; 
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

echo "<table><tbody>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>ID</td>";
echo "<td>Name</td>";
echo "<td>Value</td>";
echo "</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  { 
    echo "<tr>"
    echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>"
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>"
    echo "<td>".$row['value']."</td>"
    echo "</tr>"
}

echo "</table></tbody>";
```